# What causes "OpenCV(4.0.1) Error : Assertion failed(m.dims <= 2)"

Tags: c++, opencv

What causes this error?

> OpenCV: terminate handler is called!The last OpenCV error is :
>   OpenCV(4.0.1) Error : Assertion failed(m.dims <= 2) in
>   cv::FormattedImpl::FormattedImpl, file c : \build\master_winpack -
>   build - win64 - vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\out.cpp, line 87

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void main()
{

    int ordo[3] = { 2, 2, 2 };
    Mat obj(3, ordo, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));
    cout << obj << endl;
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: You can `cout` up to 2 dimensions. You have 3 dimensions here. If you want a 3 channel image, why don't you simply: `Mat obj(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0))`, or better: `Mat3b obj(rows, cols, Vec3b(0,0,0))`?

Comment: @Miki: I was just learning from the tutorial at random order [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html). So it is not for a particular real project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is on this line:

```
cout << obj << endl;
```

OpenCV, will only try to output 2D images (maybe 3D is too hard if it has more than 1 channel).

A possible workaround is:

```
  int ordo[3] = { 2, 2, 2 };
  cv::Mat obj(2, 2, CV_8UC2, cv::Scalar::all(0));
  std::cout << obj << std::endl;
```

Which is allowed and prints:

```
[  0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

First 2 numbers is the first "pixel". You can easily access the x,y,z coordinate doing something like:

```
// obj.at<cv::Vec2b>(y, x)[z] = uchar value
obj.at<cv::Vec2b>(1, 0)[0] = 255;
```

Which will print out:

```
[  0,   0,   0,   0;
 255,   0,   0,   0]
```

Another possibility is to create a self made printing function which takes the matrix and draws it.